# Running perf-top in a script

Tags: linux, perf

I have some intermittent performance issues that I want to capture via `perf top`. The issue is intermittent, so I want to write a script that runs `perf top` when the issue is occurring so that I can save the data and view it at a later time.

I can't seem to figure out how to get `perf top` to put its output in a file, it seems to demand to be run interactively. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
# timeout 10 perf top --stdio -E 20 > 'perf-top'
```

This does not kill perf, just leaves it running in the background forever until I create another console session, find the PID, and kill it.

```
# timeout --signal=9 10 perf top --stdio -E 20 > 'perf-top'
```

This kills perf in the expected 10 seconds, but the output is not written to the file that I specified.

Is there some special way that this command needs to be run? It works if I run it from an interactive ssh session, but I'd really like to be able to run it from a script. I'm trying to put it into an ansible task with a few other metrics-gathering programs.

Answer (score 4):

SIGKILL (`9`) isn't catchable, so it's impossible for `perf` to flush any buffered output.

Use any another signal so `perf` can clean up after receiving the signal and write output.

If the default `SIGTERM` doesn't work, then maybe try SIGHUP, SIGINT, or others.
`timeout --signal=INT`

---

`timeout 10 perf top --stdio -E 20 > perf-top` (with the default SIGTERM) works for me (as non-root) on my Arch Linux desktop.  `perf version 5.0.g1c163f4`

Answer (score 0):

use --foreground with timeout to execute with scripts